# Removing unused rows from pgfgantt gantt chart

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, pgfgantt

I am preparing a gantt chart in Overleaf using the pgfgrantt package. I use the bar and milestone top shift options to shift them up and squeeze them closer to one another. However, this leave a lot of unused rows at the bottom of the chart, as shown in the attached image. How can I get rid of these rows? The code below can reproduce the attached chart.[image]

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
   milestone top shift=-2.45,
    milestone right shift=0.3,
    group top shift = -0.05,
    bar height = 0.2,bar label node/.append style={align=right}
    ]{1}{24}
  \gantttitle{2022}{3}   \gantttitle{2023}{12} 
  \gantttitle{2024}{9} \\
  \gantttitlelist{10,11,12}{1}  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \gantttitlelist{1,...,9}{1}\\
  \ganttgroup{a}{1}{11.5} \\
  \ganttbar[bar top shift=-0.6]{b}{1}{2.5}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height=0.2, bar top shift=-1.2]{c}{3.5}{8.5} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar top shift=-1.8]{d}{8.5}{10.5} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone{e}{11} 
  %%
  \ganttgroup[group top shift = -1.6]{2\\f}{7}{15} \\
  \ganttbar[bar height = 0.4, bar top shift=-2.1]{g \\[-3pt]h}{7}{8}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height=0.4, bar top shift=-2.2]{i \\[-3pt] j}{9}{11} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height = 0.4, bar top shift=-2.3]{k \\[-3pt] l}{12}{14} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone[milestone top shift = -2.6]{m}{15}
  %%
  \ganttgroup[group top shift = -1.6]{n}{3}{23} \\
  \ganttbar[bar height = 0.2, bar top shift=-2.1]{p}{3}{5}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone[milestone top shift = -2.7]{o}{6} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height=0.2, bar top shift=-3.1]{q}{15}{18} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height = 0.4, bar top shift=-3.5]{r \\[-3pt] s}{19}{22} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone[milestone top shift = -3.8]{t}{23}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the chart is computed automatically from the number of `\ganttbar`, `\ganttgroup`, ... commands by multiplying it with a fixed length, `y unit chart`. So even if you squeeze some rows by manually shifting them, the height of the chart will remain unaffected. I recommend to set `y unit chart` to a smaller value and not to shift the bars manually.

```
\begin{ganttchart}[..., y unit chart = 7mm, ...]
```

Other problems: You shouldn't use `\\` to break lines in the label, but `\ganttalignnewline`. (Alternatively, you can set `newline shortcut` to false, but then have to use `\ganttnewline` to separate the lines in the chart).

```
\ganttbar{g \ganttalignnewline[-3pt]h}{7}{8}{jj}
```

Finally, line breaks don't seem to work in the label of `\ganttgroup` either way. If you really need two lines there, typeset the label in a `\savebox`.

```
\newsavebox\twof
\savebox\twof{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}2\\[-3pt]f\end{tabular}}
...
\ganttgroup{\usebox\twof}{7}{15}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\twof
\savebox\twof{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}2\\[-3pt]f\end{tabular}}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    bar height = 0.2,
    bar label node/.append style={align=right},
    y unit chart = 7mm
    ]{1}{24}
  \gantttitle{2022}{3} \gantttitle{2023}{12} \gantttitle{2024}{9} \\
  \gantttitlelist{10,11,12}{1}  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \gantttitlelist{1,...,9}{1}\\
  \ganttgroup{a}{1}{11.5} \\
  \ganttbar{b}{1}{2.5}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{c}{3.5}{8.5} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{d}{8.5}{10.5} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone{e}{11} \\
  %%
  \ganttgroup{\usebox\twof}{7}{15} \\
  \ganttbar[bar height = 0.4]{g \ganttalignnewline[-3pt]h}{7}{8}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height=0.4]{i \ganttalignnewline[-3pt] j}{9}{11} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[bar height = 0.4]{k \ganttalignnewline[-3pt] l}{12}{14} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone{m}{15}\\
  %%
  \ganttgroup{n}{3}{23} \\
  \ganttbar{p}{3}{5}{jj} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone{o}{6} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{q}{15}{18} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{r \ganttalignnewline[-3pt] s}{19}{22} \\
  \ganttlinkedmilestone{t}{23}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great and worked well for me, thanks for the help!